# Why is my nginx server keeping closing the connection

Tags: nginx

When trying to download a file with wget or curl from my server, it closes the connection after 1-2s (but some data were downloaded correctly)

Restarting doesn't do anything and keep-alive is enabled...

Comment: Check nginx's error log file, it contains tons of useful information

Answer (score 1):

Check available disk space, maybe nginx tries to write some kind of cache and because it can't, it close the connection